# Angular: How is a class not registered as a service or as a component treated

Tags: angular

In Angular (2/4) the usual scenarios for a class are:

- S-1: to use it as a component, register it in the Module in declarations section
- S-2: to use it as a service (singleton), register it in the Module in providers section

**But how does Angular treat the scenario when the class is *not* registered as a component or a service** (and not annotated with @Component() or @Injectable() ) ?

I recently encountered a usage for a class without annotation, without registration, but seemingly working (the usage pattern was as if it were a S-2 service). Is it the case of violating the 'singleton' pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a class, which, in ES5, will be stripped down to a function with properties on it's `prototype`. You can export is as you usually do, import it as you usually do, but you have to handle it's instantiation manually with `new MyClass(constructor arguments)`. Also, it does not qualify for dependency injection in your app, so the `new MyClass(...)` thingy has to be done every time and everywhere you need it.